# running apt-get install nvidia-current wants to downgrade the driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, apt, nvidia

When I run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` I get this:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-304 nvidia-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-352-updates nvidia-346-updates nvidia-352-updates
  nvidia-opencl-icd-352-updates
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-304 nvidia-304 nvidia-current nvidia-opencl-icd-304
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 4 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
Need to get 47.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 149 MB disk space will be freed.
```

How come?

What's the correct way to keep my Nvidia drivers up to date?

*p.s: It's a GTX770*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already nvidia installed through apt-get, your software will be updated along with all the rest of your software when you run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

There is no need to install anything else.

However, according to nvidia, you should be using version 361. If 361 is not available for your version of ubuntu (it is for 16.04) then you should use 352 which you already have installed.

Run the following commands to install version 361 if it is available it will install, otherwise, you are already good to go:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm on 14.04 so I guess there's nothing to do. I installed the 352 driver through the "software and updates" of the software centre which does it through apt get (afaik). Still it's strange that `nvidia-current` wants to remove 352 and put 304 instead. I don't think this should happen in any way.

Comment: @MinaMichael Yes, that is strange. Many people say that nvidia-current can cause problems. I've never tried it myself.