# Is it a good idea to install nvidia 361 drivers in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I learnt that for 14.04 the last driver version is `nvidia-352` but there's version 361 for 16.04. Is it a good idea to just [grab the .deb from their website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and install it on 14.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when the stable NVIDIA drivers 352 from the Ubuntu repositories are working without problems, there is no need to install newer drivers. On the other side, there have been many bug fixes and improvements since the 352 drivers were released, so it may be a good idea to upgrade to the the latest official stable NVIDIA 361 from the NVIDIA long-lived branch which are included in Ubuntu 16.04 and ... also are available for Ubuntu 14.04 from the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA.

But it is definitely not recommended to install them manually by using the installer from NVIDIA.
If you want to install NVIDIA drivers 361 - open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/769886/running-apt-get-install-nvidia-current-wants-to-downgrade-the-driver)? How is it that `apt-get` was about to downgrade my drivers on its own?? Do you know?

Comment: @MinaMichael : You're welcome ! :) nvidia-current are NVIDIA drivers 304 (it's a little bit misleading name), so when you execute sudo apt-get install nvidia-current, you install the "older" drivers 304 and downgrade them intentionally in case you have had newer drivers like nvidia-352 installed ... enjoy ubuntu experience !

Comment: I see! Of course I though it would install the "current most up-to-date version" LOL thanks for clarifying that XD