# Desktop CTR monitor goes to sleep just before login and wont wake up!

Tags: login, suspend, screen

**Is there some way to force a CRT monitor wakeup in graphics mode (vt7 Xorg)?**

Ubuntu 14.04

After I boot, I wait it to show the login screen but the CRT monitor will remain sleeping, no matter any keyboard key I hit, move the mouse or click it.

if I hit ctrl+alt+f1, the CRT monitor will wakeup and show the text vt1.

as soon I try to go back to vt7 (where Xorg is running at :0, I confirmed with `pgrep`), the CRT will promptly and instantaneously sleep again, so I cant see absolutely anything in graphics mode.

vt8 will show only a single blinking underscore after waking up the CRT monitor, so Xorg is at vt7.

The only way to make the Desktop CRT monitor wakeup is to use my notebook and connect to my Desktop thru NoMachine.

What can I do to let my Desktop CRT monitor auto wakeup again without NoMachine?

relateds:
[Screen goes to sleep at Login Screen on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825857/screen-goes-to-sleep-at-login-screen-on-ubuntu-14-04)
? [HDMI monitor turns off right before login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874814/hdmi-monitor-turns-off-right-before-login)
? [Ubuntu 16.04 sleeps / suspend before login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794055/ubuntu-16-04-sleeps-suspend-before-login-screen)